# How do I change the API name in the class generated by swagger-codegen

Tags: swagger

I am using [swagger-springmvc](https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc) and [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) to generate a Java client library for a RESTful webservice. I have written my own extension of the BasicJavaGenerator (see below) to override the package names, and can successfully generate the client library files. The "main" files generated are:

```
swagger-codegen/generated-code/java/pom.xml
swagger-codegen/generated-code/java/src/main/java/com/example/ApiApi.java
swagger-codegen/generated-code/java/src/main/java/com/example/model/*.java
```

What I can't find is how to set the name of my API to get the code generator to rename ApiApi.java to MyProjectApi.java (for example) as seems to be done in the samples included in with swagger-codegen. I have tried looking at the code generator code to override the api name, and have also tried looking both at the swagger json spec and swagger springmvc functionality to an option to set the name.

The code generator:

```scala
package com.wordnik.swagger.codegen

import com.wordnik.swagger.codegen.BasicJavaGenerator

object MyJavaGenerator extends BasicJavaGenerator {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = generateClient(args)

  // api invoker package
  override def invokerPackage = Some("com.example.api")

  // package for models
  override def modelPackage = Some("com.example.api.model")

  // package for api classes
  override def apiPackage = Some("com.example.api")
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can override this behavior as such:

```
  override def toApiName(name: String) = "MyProject" + name
```

as you see fit.  Please note that you should consider upgrading to 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT, which lives in https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/develop_2.0

Comment: Thanks so much, that works perfectly! I will give the 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT a go now.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the accepted answer - in order to get the capitalization right, you can use:

```
override def toApiName(name: String) = "MyProject" + name.capitalize
```